# Exterior algebra over graded space

Tags: exterior-algebra, graded-modules

I can't understand how to compute exterior powers in the exterior algebra  $\bigwedge V$ where $V$ is a **graded** vector space.

I know for a single (not graded), $k$-vector space, that $\bigwedge V=\bigwedge^0 V\oplus\bigwedge^2 V\oplus...$ with the convention $\bigwedge^0 V=k$ and $\bigwedge^1 V=V$ , but what happens when $V$ is graded?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exterior+algebra#over_a_super_vector_space) help?

Comment: No, I read it couple of times but nothing helps.

Comment: Something about structure of  graded algebra over graded space I believe will help

Comment: Yeah I have that experience on nLab alllllll the time :)